How do I know which replacement ceiling fan bracket matches my ceiling fan?
I have an entirely unbranded ceiling fan in my office.  A few months ago, I yawned, I stretched, I raised my arm, and I broke one of the fan blade brackets.
Don't worry, I am fine.
When I went to buy a replacement arm blade bracket, I found sellers listing the dimensions between the mounting holes.

I didn't see anyone mentioning any other dimension.  Cool, must be standardized?  Nope!  I bought the bracket and installed it, but it holds the fan blade at a different angle of attack than the other blades.  I could get away with that at low speed but medium or high wobbled over the asymmetric thrust.
I lived like that for a while until I yawned again and broke another fan blade bracket.  My particular ceiling fan has 4 blades and the second casualty was another original bracket, so I bought exactly what I had bought the first time and arranged the matching brackets opposite from each other.
My ceiling fan again offers 3 luxurious speeds, but what will I do the next time I yawn?  And more importantly, this just feels stupid.  There must be a way to identify and purchase the correct ceiling fan bracket.  In my lifestyle, it's nearly a consumable!

When I broke a bracket, I replaced all of them. I knew that the chance of an exact match was small.

@Mattman944 And Henry Ford wept. ;-(

Just replace all 4 and have some coffee.

A new cheap import ceiling fan (like your own "unbranded" unit) will do the trick. Probably less expensive than buying (ill fitting) replacement brackets. Those parts are manufacturer/model specific, and when it's made in China it aint easy to contact the manufacturer.

You can change the blade angle of attack slightly by using washers (i.e. shims) under the mounts.  Also, you may wish to consider a fan that doesn't hang so low...

@Hiesmann That's a really good idea! I measured the two brackets, they are 10.5° and 11.5°, so I need 0.06" of washers at the blade or 0.026" of washers at the fan side. Quite reasonable. Regarding fan height, I can only do so much under an 7.5' ceiling...

@MackM well, there are ceiling fans that are "ceiling hugger" low profile, or flush mount type, and there are fans that have a downrod.  Yours isn't pictured, so we don't know what type it is.

You might want to consider putting a table under that fan, so you can't easily stand directly under it.
